# Error 500 when requesting Datadog logs by Python Requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, datadog

I have the following `curl` command which works fine:

```
curl -X POST -H 'content-type: application/json' -H "DD-API-KEY: ${api_key}" -H "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: ${app_key}" \
-d '{ 
        "query": "service:my_service",
        "time": {
            "from": "2019-11-28T00:00:00Z",
            "to": "2019-11-28T16:00:00Z"
        },
        "sort": "asc",
        "limit": 1000
    }' "https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/logs-queries/list" -o output3.json5
```

Then I convert this requests to Python Requests, and the `curl` method works but Python returns a 500 error without any details.

```
import requests

def main():
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'DD-API-KEY': 'AAA',
        'DD-APPLICATION-KEY': 'XXX',
    }

    data = {
        "query": "service:my_service",
        "time": {
            "from": "now - 1h",
            "to": "now"
        },
        "sort": "asc",
        "limit": 50
    }
    response=requests.post("https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/logs-queries/list",headers=headers, data=data)
```

I tried it outside my Docker guessing that maybe connection was the key, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe `now - 1h` and `now`? In any case, [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it barely tells us anything. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. Can you get more useful information from Datadog?

Comment: @Chris I tested using now and using the datetime in the curl request. And both returns 500 error.
Reason is internal server error, and no more logs to find in the response :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point both of those at a service like [httpbin](https://httpbin.org/) to see how they differ.

Requests' `data` option for POST requests [generates form-encoded data](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) by default, while `curl` passes the JSON string through directly. You can manually encode your payload as a JSON string:

```py
import json

response = requests.post(..., data=json.dumps(data))
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

or if you have Requests version 2.4.2 or later you can use the `json` parameter to have your `dict` converted to JSON automatically:

```py
response = requests.post(..., json=data)
#                             ^^^^
```